# Right process for making a module that uses Web Sockets for the server and browser?

Tags: typescript, websocket, rxjs, typescript-typings

I'm looking at maintaining rxjs-websockets. The module uses Typescript, as does my project. Previously, the types were not inline with `ws`, the WebSocket implementation for node; so, I've [patched that module to be work with the types that `ws` uses so TypeScript works with everything](https://github.com/ohjames/rxjs-websockets/pull/49/commits/d7a2e44aaa0cbc50cc7dd61b95d517c3ab287be0#diff-f41e9d04a45c83f3b6f6e630f10117fe) **for me.**

I'll be simplifying the problem, the [types for `@types/ws` callback are defined like this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/ws),

```
onopen?: (event: { target: WebSocket }) => void;
onerror?: (event: {error: any, message: string, type: string, target: WebSocket }) => void;
onclose?: (event: { wasClean: boolean; code: number; reason: string; target: WebSocket }) => void;
onmessage?: (event: { data: WebSocket.Data; type: string; target: WebSocket }) => void;
```

However, the [types for the `@types/websocket` callback are defined like this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/websocket/index.d.ts)

```
onopen: () => void;
onerror: (error: Error) => void;
onclose: () => void;
onmessage: (message: any) => void;
```

And, the types that `rxjs-websockets` used to use were defined like this (not comparable with the callback signature from `ws`)

```
onopen?: (event: Event) => any
onclose?: (event: CloseEvent) => any
onmessage?: (event: MessageEvent) => any
onerror?: (event: ErrorEvent) => any
```

The problem is that while I am using `ws` because Node.JS does not implement the standardized WebSocket interface, others are not on the same environment. We don't want to force the inclusion of `ws` on the browser (where it doesn't work).

At the same time, if you provide a custom WebSocket factory that uses `ws`, it **should** work.

Is there anyway to make these types jive?  How do you mix server-side javascript with ad-hoc apis, with native ES6 web apis (like WebSocket)?

Worse yet, even if we fixated on the `ws` for the server (which seems pretty fine-ish), we can't `import` the types from `ws` without importing the code **too**. The idea that the *same* code works on the server and the client seems like a great idea. But, how is that possible when the interfaces aren't the same?

Is the best bet to have a `rxjs-ws` and an `rxjs-w3c-websockets`?

Comment: Well, if you're going to attempt to run the same code on client and server, it kind of goes without saying that you have to be programming to the same APIs.  The usual scheme is write a shim over the built-in interface for one side or the other to give you an interface that works like the other.

Comment: That said, one doesn't typically run the same webSocket code on client and server because typically it's a webSocket client talking to a webSocket server where one would use different code on the client and server end of things.  Why exactly are you trying to run the same webSocket code on both client and server?

Comment: @jfriend00 They're both clients.

Comment: Then, you have to make a shim on one end that makes for a common client interface.  Types can be separate from code.  There are external TypeScript definitions all the time for things that weren't originally written in TypeScript so the definitions can be separate.

Comment: As for the shim, here's a module that implements the HTML5-webSocket interface over the top of the ws library in node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html5-websocket.  Then, you could use the same type bindings in client and server.